# How to create an exe of a winforms project that uses NuGet Packages?

Tags: visual-studio

I do not know how to create an exe that can be run anywhere, not just using the 'run' button in VS. It is a WinForms project. I am using VS 2017 if that helps (It doesn't run on VS 2019 or VS 2022). I tried to follow a tutorial that taught how to make a setup wizard for VS 2017, but it somehow didn't work for me. It uses NuGet packages - CEFSharp and EasyTabs.

Comment: If you are using VS 2017, then you need a tutorial that matches the version. If you want to ask questions on a tutorial, then you'd better contact its author(s) first. Stack Overflow is a site for very specific questions on technology, so "how-to" questions are usually downvoted or closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try these steps.

1. Set the solution configuration to release mode.

[image: Solution Configuration]

2. Run your application using the run button (the green button)
   [image: Run button]
3. Once the application runs, you would be prompted to choose whether to continue debugging or stop debugging.  Choose "Continue Debugging".  At this stage, an "exe" file will be created.
4. Close your application if you need to.
5. Under Solution Explorer, right-click and select "Open Folder in File Explorer".

[image: Open Folder in File Explorer]

6. From the file explorer, you should see a folder called "bin".  Double click to enter the folder.

[image: bin folder]

7. Once inside, you would typically have two folders, "debug" and "release".  Double click on "release".

[image: release folder]

8. Once inside sort the output according to type, and look for type "Application".  That would be your exe file.

[image: Application]

Note: this is based on the assumption that your winform application is a winform application that does not have any dependencies to other libraries.  If it has, then creating a proper installer would be the best way to go.